# GCC fails to compile variadic member concept template on a variadic concept template class

Tags: c++, gcc, variadic-templates, c++20, c++-concepts

Imagine I have a variadic concept template class with a variadic concept template member.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
concept Arithmetic = std::is_arithmetic_v<T>;

template<Arithmetic... Scalars>
class Foo
{
public:
    template<Arithmetic... OtherScalars>
    Foo(OtherScalars&&... args)
    {

    }
};
```

The above code fails to compile with `GCC (trunk)` but passes with `Clang (experimental concepts)`.

*GCC compiler output*

```
source>: In instantiation of 'class Foo<int, float, double>':
<source>:20:33:   required from here
<source>:11:5: internal compiler error: in tsubst_constraint, at cp/constraint.cc:1949

   11 |     Foo(OtherScalars&&... args)
      |     ^~~

Please submit a full bug report, with preprocessed source if appropriate. See <https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/> for instructions.
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
```

#### [LIVE DEMO](https://godbolt.org/z/LqTfoS)

Is this a bug in `GCC` or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: It would be appropriate to include the compile error message in the body of your question.

Comment: @Wyck Ok, Done!

Comment: internal compiler error is certainly bug in compiler

Comment: @ÖöTiib I believe you can post this as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a bug. The output literally says so and asks for you to report a bug report.